# Building a docker container on Jenkins using a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build a docker image on a Jenkins server which uses a COPY command to copy a .war file into the container.
Jenkins can't handle to get the right build context needed for Docker to find the file I want to COPY into the container.

The error:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder191966749/auth-ms-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I have tried using the Docker Pipeline plugin from Cloudbees as well as just invoking `docker build` myself. Here is the Jenkinsfile pipeline section which is responsible for the build:

```
stage('Build Docker') {
            steps {

                script {
                
                    TAG = sh(script: "echo ${BUILD_TAG}-${env.version}", returnStdout: true)

                    dir("${buildDir}") {
                        def auth = docker.build("${env.AUTH_MS_REPO}:latest", "-f Dockerfile --build-arg ARTIFACT_NAME=\"${env.FILE}\" --build-arg EXPOSE=\"${EXPOSE}\" .")
                        auth.push()
                        auth.push("${env.AUTH_MS_REPO}:${TAG}")
                    }
            }
      }
}
```

I've tried all possible path combinations (using jenkins `dir()`, using absolute and relative paths). Jenkins never finds the build context inside `${buildDir}`.

I also verified manually on the server that the command works and all files are present.

Comment: We build docker images with `sh "docker build ..."` etc. You may try this.

Comment: I have also tried this using plain `sh "docker build ..."` and also `def exec = sh(script: "docker build ...", returnStdout: true)`. Gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **Docker** to build images on Cloudbees.
If you check [this article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019236771-How-to-build-my-own-docker-images-in-CloudBees-CI-CloudBees-Core-on-Modern-Cloud-Platforms) from Cloudbees, you will see that you need to use [Kaniko](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/using-kaniko), which is a utility that creates container images from a Dockerfile.

Main reason is that Cloudbees goes hand in hand with Kubernetes and the smart people of Google decided that Docker won't do, so they've build this utility, ie **Kaniko**, that does the same thing as Docker: builds and pushed a Docker image to a repo (you can still use the same Dockerfile).